# what is the proper tool to analyse data and find trends in my case?

Tags: data-mining, bigdata, data

I have a database of hundreds of thousands of loans. I want to find some trends in user behavior, not just some information regarding all loans together but I want to find something similar for particular users(or groups). Example of what I want to find can be formulated like: 30% of users take their loans in 10 days after they pay the previous one OR 40% of users take loan in the same time of the month +/- 1 day.
My background in software development and usually i get reports by simply making a sql query, also I sometime use SSAS. But in this case I dont know how to simply ask. one way is to make a hypothesis and then trying to prove it, but it needs so much resource to program appropriate reports in that case and also I am limited to my imagination that generates hypothesis. 
So what approach would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

To piggy-back off of @*Impul3H*, I recommend checking out [Orange Data Mining Tool](http://orange.biolab.si/).  In case you are unfamiliar with Python and think that you'd experience a steep learning curve with scikit learn, then the drag and drop interface from Orange would be a good tool for you.

Outside of clustering, I would think that a [Naive Bayes](http://machinelearningmastery.com/naive-bayes-classifier-scratch-python/) classifier may be useful for you; if your data is in categorical form.  This would be a supervised learning classification model, and is often one of the first and more easy to implement models on data in this format.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to see what are the different types of users? In that case I would suggest clustering? Clustering is an unsupervised learning algorithm that finds patterns and splits your data into the observed patterns. There are several clustering techniques and which to use depends on your data.

[scikit learn resource for clustering](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html)

If you're unsure which, just go with k means first. I suggest you read the documentation and examples in the scikit learn page!